# Adding to created Entities attributes using Magical Record

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

so I am using Magical Record in my project, and I am attempting to do the following:

```
- (void)persistNewReadingWithOneA:(NSString *)oneA oneB:(NSString *)oneB{

    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];

    FinalRead *reading1A = [FinalRead MR_createInContext:localContext];

    reading1A.a1 = oneA;
    reading1A.b1 = oneB;


    [localContext MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait];


}
```

As you can see I've persisted with a new entry and now I need to be able to update that same entry by adding to it's attributes. I tried doing the following:

```
- (void)updateReadingWithTwoA:(NSString *)twoA twoB:(NSString *)twoB{

    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];

    FinalRead *reading2A = [FinalRead MR_createInContext:localContext];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname ==[c] %@ AND lastname ==[c] %@"];
    FinalRead *finalRead = [FinalRead MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:localContext];

    reading2A.a2 = twoA;
    reading2A.b2 = twoB;


    [localContext MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait];


}
```

Any Ideas?

EDIT:

I am fetching data from a JSON response like so:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

    if (self.buttonPressed){

        //parse out the json data
        NSError* error;
        NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                              options:kNilOptions
                              error:&error];

       NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [json objectAtIndex:0]];

        [self persistNewReadingWithOneA:string
                                   oneB:nil];


    }else{

        //parse out the json data
        NSError* error;
        NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                              options:kNilOptions
                              error:&error];

        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [json objectAtIndex:0]];

        [self persistNewReadingWithOneA:nil
                                   oneB:string];



    }

}
```

and then storing to a newly created object like so:

```
- (void)persistNewReadingWithOneA:(NSString *)oneA oneB:(NSString *)oneB{

    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];

    FinalRead *reading1A = [FinalRead MR_createInContext:localContext];

    reading1A.a1 = oneA;
    reading1A.b1 = oneB;


    [localContext MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait];


}
```

The ViewController then pushes to another that asks another question where once again more JSON is parsed and stored, but into the SAME object that was just created in the previous ViewController. I have the following attributes PER object in NSManagedObject:

```
@interface FinalRead : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *a1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *b1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *a2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *b2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *a3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *b3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *a4;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *b4;

@end
```

So basically, every time that I change a new viewController I'm wanting to add to that same object until the final View has been used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update method also creates a new object:

```
FinalRead *reading2A = [FinalRead MR_createInContext:localContext];
// ... other stuff
reading2A.a2 = twoA;
reading2A.b2 = twoB;
```

And the object fetched here:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname ==[c] %@ AND lastname ==[c] %@"];
FinalRead *finalRead = [FinalRead MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:localContext];
```

is completely unused. In fact I would expect that fetch request to *crash*, because the
predicate uses `%@` formats for which no arguments are supplied.

To *update* an object, you have to fetch it first. And to fetch it you need some 
attributes which *identify* the object that you want to update. For example:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname ==[c] %@ AND lastname ==[c] %@",
       firstName, lastName];
FinalRead *finalRead = [FinalRead MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:localContext];
if (finalRead) {
    finalRead.a2 = twoA;
    finalRead.b2 = twoB;
    // ... save context ...
} else {
    // no matching object found
}
```

---

*Update:* The solution in your case might be to pass the `finalRead` object from one
view controller to the next, instead of re-fetching it in each view controller.

Comment: Okay, I see. Well the firstname and lastname was something that I found in an example. I'm not sure how to search for the newly created object in my core data model to be honest.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with how to use NSPredicate properly.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Do you have more than one `FinalRead` object in the database? Which of the many objects do you want to update?

Comment: Let me update my question so that it's a little more clear. Apologies.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Side note: I *think* that MR_contextForCurrentThread is deprecated. But that is a different issue, unrelated to *this* problem.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get any kind of error, but I'll look into that. I've updated my question so that it's a little more clear what I'm trying to accomplish. I appreciate the prompt replies.